# openssl alternative names is missing

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate-errors

I generated CA, with this [article](https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309), and stored it in my machine. Now, I want to create a server certificate and use it in my webserver. This is my generate server certificate code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# USE: ./build.sh <CERTNAME> <EXPR_DAYS>

openssl genrsa -out $1.key 2048

openssl req -new -key $1.key -out $1.csr -config ssl.config

openssl x509 -req -in $1.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out $1.pem -days $2 -sha256
```

This code is generating the certificate but **it missing the alternate names as specified** in my `ssl.config` file:

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = extensions
x509_extensions     = extensions
string_mask         = utf8only
prompt              = no

[ subject ]
countryName         = US
stateOrProvinceName = NY
localityName        = New York
organizationName    = Company
commonName          = API
emailAddress        = test@example.com

[ extensions ]
basicConstraints            = CA:TRUE
keyUsage                    = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
extendedKeyUsage            = serverAuth
subjectAltName              = @alternate_names

[ alternate_names ]
IP.1=1.2.3.4
IP.2=2.3.4.5
```

To confirm that alternative name is missing, I run:

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            79:d5:7d:02:10:fb:2e:55:1c:19:7d:13:d8:e4:cb:ee:91:16:36:34
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = Some-State, O = Company
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 13 10:38:26 2019 GMT
            Not After : Feb 27 10:38:26 2047 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = NY, L = New York, O = Company, CN = API, emailAddress = test@example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                        XXXX
                Exponent: XXXX (XXX)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
            XXXX
```

As you can see, the alternative name section is missing. I expected to see:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: IP:1.2.3.4, IP:2.3.4.5
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

This:

```
openssl x509 -req -in $1.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out $1.pem -days $2 -sha256
```

became this:

```
openssl x509 -req -in $1.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out $1.pem -days $2 -sha256 -extensions v3_req -extfile ssl.config
```